# REGEX that reads the following string including spaces and points: android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Tags: java, android, regex, kill-process

The problem with that string is that it can be written in different ways like the picture:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JFRq.png)

I need to read all the words that have string regardless of the amount of points, space and line breaks, any ideas? thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do language processing, much like the way compilers read source code to convert it into a computer program. This realm of computer science is called Lexical Analysis, and separating the different parts of the string you have given into meaningful bits is called "tokenization".

I would suggest reading about [Lexical Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization). Then consider creating your own grammar for the input language, and then using free software like [GNU Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) to create a parser for your grammar.